# importing installed python module x.features2d from Opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have installed Opencv3 module on my Ubuntu 14.04 system and the installation of sub-modules done without problem. But when I called x.features2d in my code after importing cv2, as shown in the code below

```
import sys
import cv2
import cv2.xfeatures2d
import numpy as np
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
img_bgr=cv2.imread('sc2.png')
img_gray=cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template=cv2.imread('template.png',0)
w, h=template.shape[::-1]
res=cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold=0.7
loc = np.where(res >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
 cv2.rectangle(img_bgr, pt, (pt[0]+w, pt[1]+h), (0,255,0), 2)
freakExtractor=cv2.xfeatures2d.FREAK_create()
keypoints,descriptors=freakExtractor.compute(img_bgr,keypoints)
cv2.imshow('detected', img_bgr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

it gives me the error of not being able to find x.features2d module as below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
import cv2.xfeatures2d
ImportError: No module named xfeatures2d
```

I tried to re-install it again and also installed opencv-contrib, but same problem happened. 
Any idea to solve it?

Comment: Do you install `xfeatures2d` module?

Answer (score 0):

You have not given many details on your installation process.

All the contrib features such as xfeatures2d are no longer part of the prebuilt libraries. This means xfeatures2d will only work if you compile openCV yourself.

Example of how to do that (e.g. for Windows) is given here:

https://putuyuwono.wordpress.com/2015/04/23/building-and-installing-opencv-3-0-on-windows-7-64-bit/